# Terraform loop newbie issue

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider

I'm trying to deploy a few VMs via Terraform to Azure, and I have an issue with the loop.

My code:
Part of **variables.tf**

```
variable "vm_instance_detail" {
type = map
default = {
    vm1 = {
        name = "vm-01"
        size = "Standard_B1ls"
    }
    vm2 = {
        name = "vm-02"
        size = "Standard_B1ls"
    }
} }
```

**main.tf**

```
 resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic" {
  for_each = var.vm_instance_detail

  name                  = each.value.name
  location              = var.location
  resource_group_name   = var.name_rg

  ip_configuration {
      name                          = var.ip_configuration.name
      subnet_id                     = data.azurerm_subnet.subnet.id
      private_ip_address_allocation = var.ip_configuration.private_ip_address_allocation
  }
  depends_on = [azurerm_resource_group.rg]
}

resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "VM" {
  for_each = var.vm_instance_detail
  name                  = each.value.name
  resource_group_name   = var.name_rg
  location              = var.location
  size                  = each.value.size
  admin_username        = var.admin_username
  admin_password        = var.admin_password
  disable_password_authentication = var.disable_password_authentication

  network_interface_ids = [
    azurerm_network_interface.nic[each.key].id,
  ]
```

When I tries to do terraform plan got the error:

```
Error: Cycle: azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.vm["vm2"], azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.vm["vm1"]
```

Maybe who has any advice on my case?
Thanks.

Comment: Are these all the resources you have defined? This is a cyclic dependency issue which means terraform cannot create resources using its graph because there is probably an unneeded `depends_on` somewhere else.

Comment: You don't have `azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.vm` resource in your question. This means that the code presented here, is not the one that generates the error.

Comment: @MarkoE Thanks for your hint. I have removed ```depends_on``` from ```azurerm_linux_virtual_machine``` and everything works fine.

Comment: Hi @RahulKumarShaw-MT, Yes, the suggested solution worked in my case. I cannot mark a comment Marko E as a solution. Please a moderator marks his comment as a solution to my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You [Marko E](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8343484/marko-e) for your suggestion and [MTLTR_](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9742740/mtltr) you resolved your issues by applying the suggestion. I have also tested in my enviroment and found the issue with `depends_on = [azurerm_resource_group.rg]` . This is unneeded parameter you were mentioning. Sharing the full code it could help other community member who might be encounter the same issue in future.

```
provider "azurerm"{
  features{

  }
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "v-XXXXXXXee"
  # location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "example-network"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "internal"
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic" {
  for_each = var.vm_instance_detail

  name                  = each.value.name
  location              = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name   = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  ip_configuration {
      name                          = "internal"
      subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.example.id
      private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
  
}

resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "VM" {
  for_each = var.vm_instance_detail
  name                  = each.value.name
  resource_group_name   = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location              = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  size                  = each.value.size
  admin_username        = var.admin_username
  admin_password        = var.admin_password
  disable_password_authentication = var.disable_password_authentication

  network_interface_ids = [
    azurerm_network_interface.nic[each.key].id,
  ]

  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = "16.04-LTS"
    version   = "latest"
  }

}
```

[image]

OutpUt --

[image]